# trying to insert std::pair into std::set

Tags: c++, stl

i can't understand what the error is in this code:

```
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(unsigned int a) : _a(a) { }
        A() : _a(0) { }
        unsigned int a() const { return _a; }
    private:
        unsigned int _a;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B(unsigned int b) : _b(b) { }
        B() : _b(0) { }
        unsigned int b() const { return _b; }
    private:
        unsigned int _b;
};

void display(const Point& point)
{
    //cout << "A: " << point.first.a() << ", B: " << point.second.b() << endl;
}

typedef pair <A, B> Point;
typedef set <Point> List;

main()
{
    A a(5);
    B b(9);

    List list;
    List::iterator it;
    Point point;

    point = make_pair(a, b);

    it = list.begin();

    list.insert(point); // <--- error here

    //display(point);
}
```

error is this:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_tree.h:62,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/set:60,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_pair.h: In function ‘bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = A, _T2 = B]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h:230:   instantiated from ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = std::pair<A, B>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_tree.h:1170:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = std::pair<A, B>, _Val = std::pair<A, B>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::pair<A, B> >, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<A, B> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<A, B> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_set.h:411:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const _Key&) [with _Key = std::pair<A, B>, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<A, B> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<A, B> >]’
test.cpp:48:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_pair.h:154: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x->std::pair<A, B>::second < __y->std::pair<A, B>::second’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_pair.h:154: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__y->std::pair<A, B>::first < __x->std::pair<A, B>::first’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_pair.h:154: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x->std::pair<A, B>::first < __y->std::pair<A, B>::first’
```

Comment: If you want to use a an `std::set` to hold classes `A`, `B`, or a `std::pair<A,B>`, then your classes must be LessThanComparable: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/LessThanComparable.html . This is because `set` is implemented as a red-black tree, which is ordered.

Comment: @phooji: you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Bill: It was @Matteo Italia's 'find' that the formatting was causing the missing < > (leading to several wrong answers including my own, which is now deleted). Of course Matteo's answer was initially wrong, but then it got corrected. My comment was just to tie things over ;)

Answer (score 13):

You are trying to use `std::set` <s>with an element type that does not have ordering (`std::pair`)</s>, while a set needs that its elements have "a specific strict weak ordering criterion".

---

***Update***: actually `std::pair` *does* provide an `operator<` (thanks *@UncleBens*), that is defined in terms of the `operator<` of its components; so the problem lies in your `A` and `B` not providing a comparison operator; you should write an `operator<` for `A` and `B`.

In alternative, since an `operator<` in general doesn't really make sense for points, you can create a comparison functor for your `Point`s and pass it as the second template argument for `std::set`.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Good eye on noticing (I'm guessing) that the compiler error had missing angle brackets :)

Comment: Actually `std::pair` has ordering. `A` and `B` don't. (Read the error messages.)

Comment: @phooji: actually it went in another way; I noticed that the post had "strange" `#` signs (they were the musical ones instead of the programming ones), so I started to edit the question to fix them. Editing I noticed that the code was in `<pre>` blocks with only some angle brackets replaced with `&gt;` and `&lt;`; saving the edit the missing brackets came back to life, making the existing answers invalid. :)

Comment: If you create a set of pairs, where you only compare the value of the first element of the pair, you have just created a map. Why not use std::map?

Answer (score 9):

`pair` and `set` are templates, not classes. You need to do e.g:

```
typedef pair<A, B> Point;
typedef set<Point> List;
```

A template becomes a class when you instantiate it, e.g. `std::set<int> theset;` creates the *class* `set<int>` from the *class template* `set`.

EDIT: As phooj pointed out, you need both A and B to have a comparison operator, `operator<`. See Matteo Italia's answer.

Comment: Well played, sir. Outdrew me by a solid half minute :)

Comment: The code he posted had the `<A, B>` in place, but they were removed by Markdown because he used the `<pre>` tag instead of the usual 4 spaces. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Eric: looks like the actual problem lies in `A` and `B` not satisfying the less-than-comparable concept. See my comment to the question.

Comment: @phooji: good point. That'll likely be the next question once he's edited his code to match the real code

Comment: @Eric: Looks like the templates params were not the problem in the first place -- have a closer look at the compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <set>

int main(){

    typedef pair<int, int> pairs; //creating pair as default data type 
    pairs p[5]; //array of pair objects
    for (int i =0; i<5; i++){
        p[i].first= (i+1)*10; //inserting first element of pair
        p[i].second = (i+1); //inserting first element of pair
    }
    set<pairs> s;   //set to sort pair
    set<pairs> :: iterator it; //iterator to manipulate set

    for (int i =0; i<5; i++){
        s.insert(p[i]); //inserting pair object in set
    }

    for (it = s.begin(); it!=s.end(); it++){
        pairs m = *it; // returns pair to m

    cout<<m.first<<" "<<m.second<<endl; //showing pair elements
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what's the type of the elements of the `set` and `pair` are going to be.

Changing the lines

`typedef pair Point` to `typedef pair<A, B> Point` and 
`typedef set List` to `typedef set<Point> List` should fix your problem.

One pedantic comment: Naming a `set` as `List` kind of misleads when you read the code.

Comment: Aaand... maybe also define `Point` properly?

Answer (score 1):

For any user type, that is being stored in an associative container like set/map the type definition must provide ' < ' operation on it.