# Check if a c++ struct is in a set

Tags: c++

I have a structure of data declared the following way

```
struct foo{
int first;
int second;
};
```

I then add elements of type `foo` into a set.

Then after a while i will check if my `foo myfoo` is in the set.  My question is how do this?  Currently I am trying

```
myset.count(myfoo)
```

However the compiler tells me i need to define the '<' operator and I am unsure how or why I need to do this. Why can I know just do a

`inline bool operator==` definition what does it need the '<' for?

Comment: Why not simply use [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)? It's got everything you need already.

Comment: The compiler probably gives you this error when you try to create the set or insert an item. `std::set` works (by default) by comparing elements using `std::less` which calls `operator<` for your struct, so you need to implement it if you want to use `std::set`.

Comment: @TheDude  I don't know why I did not think of that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an *ordered* container. You have to provide it with the ordering of the elements. By default, `std::set<T>` will use `bool operator< (T, T)` (via [`std::less<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)), although any type that satisfies [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) is allowable.

Your struct has the same data members as `std::pair<int, int>`, but lacks all the operations defined for `pair`. You can add the required operations, or use `pair`

Comment: however here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278613/trying-to-insert-stdpair-into-stdset it says that pair does not have a < operator

Comment: No, that is saying that if for `class A` there is no `bool operator< (A, A)` or similar, then the `<` for `std::pair<A, ...>` (and `std::pair<..., A>`) is an ill-formed template. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp)